# dotnet cli can't detect installed package?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I was following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli with dotnet cli on alpine-linux. After executing

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc WebApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.RegisterConfirmation"
```

Got following error(s):

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'identity'...
Running the generator 'identity'...
The given key '"Account.Register' was not present in the dictionary.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:04.45
Account.Login: No such file or directory
Account.Logout: No such file or directory
Account.RegisterConfirmation": No such file or directory
```

Then I tried

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help
```

ond got

```
Usage: aspnet-codegenerator [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  generator  Name of the generator. Check available generators below.

Options:
  -p|--project             Path to .csproj file in the project.
  -n|--nuget-package-dir   
  -c|--configuration       Configuration for the project (Possible values: Debug/ Release)
  -tfm|--target-framework  Target Framework to use. (Short folder name of the tfm. eg. net46)
  -b|--build-base-path     
  --no-build               

No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.

RunTime 00:00:00.90
```

Then I ran

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

which ran successfully. I confirmed that by looking at my `WebApp1.csproj` file, which indeed contained the following line

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.4" />
```

But running above mentioned erroneous commands yielded same output. As a bonus, I ran

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity --help
```

and got following output

Usage: aspnet-codegenerator [arguments] [options]

```
Arguments:
  generator  Name of the generator. Check available generators below.

Options:
  -p|--project             Path to .csproj file in the project.
  -n|--nuget-package-dir   
  -c|--configuration       Configuration for the project (Possible values: Debug/ Release)
  -tfm|--target-framework  Target Framework to use. (Short folder name of the tfm. eg. net46)
  -b|--build-base-path     
  --no-build               

Selected Code Generator: identity
No code generator found with the name 'identity'.

No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.

RunTime 00:00:00.90
```

unfortunately, my skills of googling could not *scaffold* up with bugginess and overall mess of this **most loved framework**, and what better place to seek solutions, than the community which rated it as **the most loved framework** in the first place.

> Update:

As noted in the first comment, dotnet cli(or maybe my shell) behaved weirdly with double quotes, so I tried running(with single quotes this time)

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc WebApp1.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files 'Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.RegisterConfirmation'
```

and got this trimmed down version of the first cited error:

```
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'identity'...
Running the generator 'identity'...
A file matching the name Account.Register.cs.cshtml was not found within any of the folders: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:04.57
```

while running same command with no quotes at all resulted in practically the same error as with double quotes.

Curiously, the line `A file matching the name Account.Register.cs.cshtml was not found within any of the folders:` may appear at the end of the message on some runs, indicating that the 'folders' which were being searched for Account.Register.cs.cshtml file is either null or empty string and not all of that `at...at...at...` unhelpful stuff.

> Another update: shell edition

All the commands discussed above were run with `rc` shell from plan9port. When run with posix shell like `ash`, running with double quotes yields same output as with single quotes with `rc`, while running with single quotes eliminates `A file matching the name Account.Register.cs.cshtml was not found within any of the folders:` message. Running with no quotes at all results in same output from dotnet command as with single quotes, but obviously posix shell picks up those semicolons as end of command and tries to execute nonsense.

Comment: `'"Account.Register'` this seems weird to me. Seems like the CLI did not trim the quotes around your argument...

Comment: mstaessen, it somewhat had to do stuff with the shell I was using, but at the end of the day `No code generators available` error prevails.